# jQuery add remove selected class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add active class to my li list and it works perfectly but I don't want to remove active class if someone click already selected li.

Here is my code.

```
$('.nav li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

So tried this way but no any luck.

```
$('.nav li.active').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f9hr5Lgf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
$('.nav li').click(function() {
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

By removing `active` class from all `li` items, then adding new `active` class for current item.

Answer (score 1):

try this. Goodluck

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
   $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```